# Proof verification in multi-variable calculus using $\epsilon-\delta$ statement

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, solution-verification

$$f(x,y)=2x+3y\implies \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(a,b)}{f(x,y)}=2a+3b$$

Prove the above using only the definition below: :
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(a,b)}{f(x,y)}=L  \text{ if }  \forall\epsilon>0, \exists\delta>0 \text{ s.t. } \forall(x,y) \text{ in } D_f, |f(x,y)-L|<\epsilon \text{ whenever }  \sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}<\delta$$

**My attempt:**
Is it correct?

Substitute $f(x,y)=2x+3y$ and $L=2a+b$ in $|f(x,y)-L|$
$$|(2x+3y)-(2a+3b)|$$
Rearrange and split the absolute value
$$\leq|(2x-2a)|+|(3y-3b)|$$
Rewrite it in terms of squares and square roots:
$$\leq\sqrt{(2x-2a)^2}+\sqrt{(3y-3b)^2}$$
Move the constant out of the square root, and change the 2 to a 3:
$$\leq3\sqrt{(x-a)^2}+3\sqrt{(y-b)^2}$$
We then wish to show:
$$|f(x,y)-L|\leq3\sqrt{(x-a)^2}+3\sqrt{(y-b)^2}<\epsilon$$
Choose $\delta$ such that:
$$\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}\leq\sqrt{(x-a)^2}+\sqrt{(y-b)^2}<\delta$$
Multiply both sides of the last inequality by 3:
$$3\sqrt{(x-a)^2}+3\sqrt{(y-b)^2}<3\delta$$
Let $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{3}$:
$$3\sqrt{(x-a)^2}+3\sqrt{(y-b)^2}<3\frac{\epsilon}{3}=\epsilon$$

And we are done.

Comment: You are first fixing $\delta$ giving a condition then you again change the value of $\delta$ which is circular reasoning

Answer (score 2):

You must start from $\sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2} < \delta$. If it is, we have $|x-a| < \delta$ and $|y-b| < \delta$. Therefore,
$$
|f(x,y)-L| < 2\delta + 3\delta = 5 \delta
$$
Choose $\delta = \epsilon/5$.

Comment: Your proof is shorter and quite elegant. However, is what I have done incorrect?

Comment: @Starlight I am on the phone. (Unable to write equations). You falsely derived sqrt + sqrt < delta from sqrt < delta because sqrt + sqrt can be larger than delta. Would you try to produce an example?

Comment: You are correct. It does not work in general. That is why I have written "choose delta".

Comment: @Starlight Yes. You cannot choose delta twice.

Comment: Isn't Delta a variable which you need to find. So, if you have two integration signs, and you get two constants, you combine and only need one. Similarly, even in your proof, you set the value of delta at the end of your proof. Aren't you choosing the value then?

Comment: @Starlight You wrote 'Choose $\delta$' and then wrote 'Let $\delta = \epsilon/3$. I think both of them are choices. You can 'choose $\delta$' explicitly whenever you want but it has to be done only once. It's best to 'choose' $\delta$ at the introduction of $\delta$, but we usually defer it until the end of the proof.

Comment: If you feel that you are still astray, I recommend you refer to the first-order logic (or more general logic). Many people plunge right into analysis without knowing how to properly handle quantifiers as I did.